# page-break-inside doesn't work with hidden table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I some CSS similar to this:

```
table#id {
  display : none;
}

@media print {
  table#id {
    display : block;
  }
  .no-page-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
}
```

Each td contains a div.no-page-break. The problem I'm having is that there are page breaks inside the tds *unless the table is made visible before opening the print dialogue*. If I emulate print media in the dev tools and print, it works fine. If I display the table before `window.print()` and hide it afterwards it also works, although I'd like to avoid this hack. Anyone have any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried moving `.no-page-break` to the non-print css? Perhaps the browser needs this information beforehand. It shouldn't make any difference on-screen, as `table#id` will still be hidden.

Comment: I tried this it didn't help, thanks though.